# Find the real Parent Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that runs out of an iframe.

To logout I run the following JavaScript with a URL and this works fine.

```
 window.parent.location.href
```

I catch I have is sometimes if I don't exit the site correctly and then reconnect I endup with 2 iframes (potentially more).

Is there a way to make the following JavaScript find the outer most (the true parent) of all potential iframes?

```
 window.parent.location.href
```

I want to make sure no matter how many iframes are present the redirection will still occur.

any advice would be great... thx

Comment: What you're doing is JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: @adarshr. You shouldn't have removed the `jQuery` tag, that means `jQuery` answers are valid!

Comment: @gdoron I can't see how jQuery could ever be useful in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) instead of `window.parent`

Answer (score 0):

```
topParent = window;

while (topParent.parent) {
    topParent = topParent.parent; 
}

// do whatever you want on topParent
```